# How to read parquet file with PySpark 1.6?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs

I can read regular file with:

```
textFile = sc.textFile("README.md")
```

but how to read Parquet file?

Answer (score 0):

```
parquetFile = sqlContext.read.parquet("people.parquet")

or in your case

parquetFile = sc.read.parquet("people.parquet")
```

I would read the documentation here for more information: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-metastore-parquet-table-conversion

Answer (score -1):

```
data = sqlContext.read.parquet("/tmp/testParquet")
display(data)
```